# Append pdf extension to link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, append, pdfkit

I know this has to be a duplicate question - I did search for it, but could not find any answers.

I'm trying to do a simple link to some documents from the index view of my rails application.  I'm using the wkhmtltopdf plugin via the PDFkit gem.  I'm able to simply append the .pdf extension to any page and get a pdf copy.  That part works great, I just can seem to figure out the proper syntax to append a format.  Here's what I have so far:

```
<tr>
    shortened for brevity's sake
            <td><%= link_to 'Show', certification %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_certification_path(certification) %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', certification, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
            <td><%= link_to "Download PDF", certification_path(@certification, :format => "pdf") %></td>
</tr>
```

I was trying to follow Ryan's method from the [PDFkit Railscast Episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit?autoplay=true), but it seems his method must be deprecated or I might have done something wrong.

Comment: Looks correct, what does that link_to produce as html?

Comment: I get a `ActionController::UrlGenerationError` error.   `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"certifications", :format=>"pdf", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]`  - obviously missing the :id parameter, but that is not required when using the "show" link above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<tr>
    shortened for brevity's sake
            <td><%= link_to 'Show', certification %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_certification_path(certification) %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', certification, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
            <td><%= link_to "Download PDF", certification_path(@certification, :format => "pdf") %></td>
</tr>
```

Okay from your code it seems you have used certification and @certification. From your comment before which says nil doesn't exist, @certifcation doesn't have any value in it.

So i believe the correct fix in your case is.

```
<td><%= link_to "Download PDF", certification_path(certification, :format => "pdf") %></td>
```